# Can't have function named default in php

Tags: php, class, function, default

Ok, this is very unexpected and it annoys me. I have function called default() in all my classes. But, I can't call it for some reason. I guess it's because of 'default:' in switch statement (which I don't use at all).

Is this really true that I can't name my function default() in php or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DEFAULT, expecting T_STRING in 
C:\Users\Jinxed\Desktop\WebTrgovina\app\c\Controller.c.php on line 8
```

And here's the code in question:

```
<?php
abstract class Controller {
    protected $view;
    function __construct() {
    }
    abstract function default();
    function getView(){
        return $this->view;
    }
}
```

Code works fine when I rename default to something else, but this is annoying, is there any solution to have function named default()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a reserved word as a class function. You can, however, use [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call):

```
<?php
abstract class Controller {

    public function _default($some, $args) {}

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if ($name === 'default') {
            //return call_user_func_array(array($this, '_default'), $arguments); // has args
            return $this->_default(); // simpler
        }
    }
}
```

Which will permit you to do `$foo->default()`. A better idea though would be to not choose an implementation/api that relies upon using reserved words for method names.

Comment: A better idea would be for PHP to fix their goofy parser so people can write sensible OOP code without having to resort to hacky magic just to use a reasonable method name.

Answer (score 8):

`default` is a reserved word in PHP.

Here's the list: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Answer (score 3):

It's on the [list of reserved keywords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), so nothing unexpected there.  If you *really* need those names, you can use `__call` - see the comments on the keywords page for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you cannot have a function named `default`. Annoying, but that's PHP.

Comment: @Jon you said that I can't call it normally, but how about abnormally? + any good reason why is that so? Couldn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: Read the list of reserved keywords page of the manual - it gives examples of workarounds if you really need them.

Comment: @Jinx: What Cylindric said. But I really wouldn't recommend it, it's non-standard and there are corner cases where the abstraction leaks and it shows that you are only faking it.

Comment: Ok, got it, I'll just rename it to defolt, though this is kind of weird.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute to AD7six's answer (this should be a comment, bu I can't), adding that if you use an IDE that supports PHPDoc, you can add this before the class declaration to make its autocompletion know these fake methods exist.

```
/**
 * show off @method
 * @method whateverItReturns default()
 */
class foo {
...
```